# How to handle Lock shared read on variable in ssis package?

Tags: c#, ssis

I ran into a state that ssis package freezes and can not take any action,This happens when an error occur inside a `forEach loop container` that i use variable named '`User::vRequestId`' and i have a `error event handler` that uses the same variable, When ssis want to execute event handler everything freezes and log following message

> Lock shared read on 'User::vRequestId' failed. Error 0x80070102

I need to have `vRequestId` in my event handler but i do not know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: What is the scope of `vRequestId`? In the Variable menu, on [Grid Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9daEd.png) check the [Scope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcCzg.png) property

Comment: I checked it out....It's scope is for the whole package not only the loop container.